# What is that hole on the front portion of the empennage of a CRJ-1000?

Tags: feature-identification, bombardier-crj

I've noticed that there is a hole on the front tip of the "dorsal fin" of the CRJ-1000. I've been thinking that it would be logical if that's the intake for its APU unit. But I'm not really sure.

[image]
<sub>Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Garuda_Indonesia_Bombardier_CRJ1000_@BPN.jpg</sub>

Comment: I've added a picture highlighting what I *think* you must be refering to, but it's worth validating that

Comment: Yup thank you for that jamiec

Answer (score 10):

It is the [Ram Air Inlet Duct](https://xplanecrj.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/ch02.pdf) for the cabin air system. It normally acts as cooling air for the packs but can also be used as an alternate vent source in an emergency.

> The cooling efficiency of each air conditioning pack is enhanced by
>   ram air cooling via a heat exchanger. Ram air enters through an inlet
>   at the abse of the vertical stabilizer and passes through the pack
>   heat exchangers and then exits overboard. In case of failure of both
>   packs, ram air can be used as the sole source of ventilation. This is
>   accomplished by opening the ram-air valve via the RAM AIR switch. Ram
>   air then enters the occupied areas through the normal vents.

[image]

([source](https://xplanecrj.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/ch02.pdf))